# No dejar eliminar un usuario si es responsable de un proyecto y si no es Responsable de un Proyecto dejarlo eliminar

Tags: javascript, django, django-models

Como puedo hacer para que si un Usuario es responsble de un Proyecto no me deje eliminarlo pero si no es responsable de ningun proyecto si me deje eliminarlo

Mis models

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
id_usuario = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombres_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=60)
apellidos_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class AsignacionProyecto(models.Model):
id_asignacion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
id_proyecto = models.ForeignKey('Proyecto', models.DO_NOTHING, 
db_column='id_proyecto')
id_usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, 
db_column='id_usuario')

class Proyecto(models.Model):
id_proyecto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
codigo_proyecto = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
nombre_proyecto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
id_responsable = models.ForeignKey('Responsable', models.DO_NOTHING, 
db_column='id_responsable')
```

Intente algo así pero no tuve exito mi vista de delete_usu.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Borrar usuario</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p class="delete-text">Esta seguro que quiere borrar  al usuario
      <strong>{{ usuario.nombres_usuario }} &nbsp; {{ usuario.apellidos_usuario }} </strong>?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="delete-btn btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
  </div>

<script>
  $(".delete-btn").each(function () {
if (Usuario.id_usuario = AsignacionProyecto.id_usuario) {
        return confirm("No es posible Eliminar porque el Usuario es responsable del proyecto")     
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".delete-btn").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var a = confirm("Sure?");
      if(a){}
      else if(!a){}
      });
      }); 
        } 
      else {
         $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
}
     });

    
</script>
</form>
```

Lo que necesito es que SI un usuario esta asigando a un proyecto "NO PUEDA SER ELIMINADO" pero si el usuario NO esta asignado a un proyecto "SI PUEDA SER ELIMINADO"

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no tengo mucha experiencia
Gracias,

Comment: Creo que es por las FK's debes eliminar o cambiar al responsable del proyecto por otro en tu base de datos, luego de eso no deberías tener problemas para eliminarlo, también puedes hacerlo directo desde la base y ahí te indicara si tiene alguna FK involucrada.

Comment: Vale, agrege informacion que creo que puede ser util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar a tu modelo el atributo `on_delete=PROTECT` que no deja borrar el registro vinculado en cambio si es `on_delete=CASCADE` eliminará ambos. Te dejo un ejemplo con tu modelo

```
 class Proyecto(models.Model):
   id_proyecto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   codigo_proyecto = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
   nombre_proyecto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   id_responsable = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=PROTECT)
```

Considera que un "Usuario" es el responsable de un proyecto según lo que explicas. Por lo que se debe crear la FK vinculando al modelo Usuario como está en el ejemplo. Al intentar eliminar django te debería dar un error indicando que está vinculado. Si te sale el error está OK, verifica en tu BD o Admin de django que no te dejó eliminar